# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY and UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, exception, compilation, android-studio

So I'm working on an android app that implements the Caldroid library. At first when I tried to build the app I got a DexException. I fixed that by deleting the `android-support-v4.jar` file from `Syncc/app/build/exploded-aar/Syncc/caldroid/unspecified/libs`

'Syncc' is the name of the app and 'app' is the module. I'm not quite sure what that means (If someone could clarify that I'd be very grateful) but it's the way AndroidStudio makes it.

So after removing that file when I try to build the app it works but installing it to my device doesn't. The terminal says the following:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_n7100-4d005d114bf9604f
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.nttkjwmp.syncc.app
Installing com.nttkjwmp.syncc.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.nttkjwmp.syncc.app"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.nttkjwmp.syncc.app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

Here is the terminal output when I put the file back in:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Nicolas\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\dex\debug C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\classes\debug C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\dependency-cache\debug C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-dcbacb5a563a38baf2818d3992287104d67e74f2.jar C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-1d8979f21bebf58bb6900d1b0d10af9c29510f44.jar C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-848439748d02ee11d97f22ad9f7789545209e0f1.jar C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\date4j-b11e34e16255b8734f64de0013eac10517e12be4.jar C:\Users\Nicolas\AndroidStudioProjects\Syncc\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-a9f29dd44ea69fc9776ae436c7b280cb22ffdec4.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

So can anyone point out what I'm missing here? Do I have to delete another file or maybe add something to a gradle file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your device include the Google extensions (i.e. Play Store &c)?

Comment: Yes I have flashed stock gapps package by pa to my device

Comment: by any chance are you using google maps api v1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some library required by your app via `<uses-library>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` is missing on device.
If this is `com.google.android.maps` try replacing it by Google Play Services.

Comment: Thanks this worked! It wasn't Play Services it was something else. I removed it and I can install the app now. I thought I had to include caldroid in the AndroidManifest? The app is now force closing. Does this have anything to do with that? The logcat doesn't say anything...

Comment: I already fixed it. Some problem with the FragmentTransaction. Many thanks!